# Why PHP doesn't allow to declare static closure property?

Tags: php, properties, static, closures, default-value

I want to implement a mechanism, when I set a closure inside class's property, and I'll use this closure later to setup header content.
[image]

Is there a way to implement such behavior?

Comment: Actual code, not pictures of code please.

Comment: you could do this by using a static method to declare your closure of the static variable like `public static function init(){self::$coucou = function() {echo 'coucou';};}` and call it that way `test::init();` `(test::$coucou)();`. By the way i do not understant the relation with the question of Gled and the post of the duplicate link, but i surely don't get something. So I can't answer anymore